# Scrolling to active item on page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I got this sidebar, and when you click a link there, the page changes, the active item on the sidebar changes, but the sidebar stays the same.

I noticed that on smaller screens when there's a scroll on a sidebar, if you click on of the lower items, in the next page the sidebar will be scrolled all the way up, so you can't see the active item. I want to make it so that when the page is ready the scroll goes to the active item.

I've looked around, but can't seem to make it work. Here's the (simplified) code:

```
<nav class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 d-none d-sm-block bg-light sidebar">
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column" id="sidebar10">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" id="formularios9" data-parent="#sidebar10" href="#togglecontr1">Formulários</a>
                <div class="collapse" id="togglecontr1">
                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="forms1" href="{{ route('layouts.forms1') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">check_box</i>Forms1</a></li>      
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="forms2" href="{{ route('layouts.forms2') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">check_box</i>Forms2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="forms3" href="{{ route('layouts.forms3') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">check_box</i>Forms3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" id="subprocess2" data-parent="#sidebar10" href="#togglecontr2">Sub-processos</a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="togglecontr2">
                        <ul class="nav nav-list">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess1" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz1') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>matriz1</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess2" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz2') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>matriz2</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess3" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz3') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>matriz3</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

As for the script, I looked around and found this little script that I adjusted, but I can't seem to make it work.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

var $scroll = $('.sidebar');

    if($('a').hasClass("active")){
    var $this = $(this);
    $scroll.scrollTop($this.position().top + $scroll.scrollTop())
}

});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

When you do: `$('a').hasClass("active")`, it checks for all `<a>` in the document.
I suggest you to select `<a>` according to its parent for example.
And here, `this` doesn't represent the a but the `window` itself. So with your code : `$this.position().top`, it will generate the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined
```

... because `window` doesn't have the method `position()` of jQuery

So you can change your code like this:

```
var $scroll = $('.sidebar');
$('.nav-item > a').each(function () {
   if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $scroll.scrollTop($(this).position().top + $scroll.scrollTop())
   }
})
```

Now this represent `<a>` into the context function of `$('.nav-item > a').each()`

Hope it helps you.

Comment: As I read your answer it made a lot of sense and I was about to make it the accepted answer, but I'm trying it and it ain't working. I'll keep testing following your logic, I'll post back if it works. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this (edited JS code)?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $scroll = $('.sidebar');
    if ($('a.active').length)
       $scroll.scrollTop($(this).position().top + $scroll.scrollTop())

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to change the way you were targeting `'a.active'`, try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var $scroll = $('.sidebar');

$(this).scrollTop($('a.active').position().top);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 d-none d-sm-block bg-light sidebar">
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column" id="sidebar10">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" id="formularios9" data-parent="#sidebar10" href="#togglecontr1">Formulários</a>
                <div class="collapse" id="togglecontr1">
                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="forms1" href="{{ route('layouts.forms1') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">check_box</i>Forms1</a></li>      
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="forms2" href="{{ route('layouts.forms2') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">check_box</i>Forms2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="forms3" href="{{ route('layouts.forms3') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">check_box</i>Forms3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" id="subprocess2" data-parent="#sidebar10" href="#togglecontr2">Sub-processos</a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="togglecontr2">
                        <ul class="nav nav-list">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess1" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz1') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>matriz1</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="active nav-link" id="contrprocess2" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz2') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>matriz2</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess3" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz3') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>matriz3</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contrprocess4" href="{{ route('layouts.documentos.matriz4') }}"><i class="material-icons" id="sidebaricons">assignment</i>4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

A tricky point you may consider is to only scroll if needed and the active tab is not visible in the viewport

So you need to check if the active selected tab is not in viewport

```
scrollToActiveTab(elementId) {
                const element= document.getElementById(elementId);
                if (element && !this.isInViewport(element)) {
                    element.scrollIntoView({
                        behavior: 'smooth',
                    });
                }
        };

isInViewport(element) {
            const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            return (
                rect.top >= 0 &&
                rect.left >= 0 &&
                rect.bottom <=
                    (window.innerHeight ||
                        document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
                rect.right <=
                    (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
            );
        },
```